# Should the intake fan of a power supply be pointed upwards or downwards if the computer resides on carpet floor?

Tags: power-supply, fan, cooling

I have a chassis where one can hook up the PSU on the bottom only. I have a carpet floor which means that dust is more prone to get into the chassis. There is a filter on the bottom of the chassis, but it's not fine enough and I don't want to purchase a finer one. However, I purchased two plastic cutting boards that I'll place on each end of the chassis to limit dust intake and to ensure enough clearance from the bottom.

Nevertheless, I need to decide it I want to mount the PSU so that the intake fan points downwards towards the outside carpet floor, or inwards towards the video card. I believe the former will result in cooler air being sucked in but more dust being collected over time.

The PC is at the lower end in the high-end spectrum of specs in a full sized chassis with one front fan and one rear fan.

Which is less worse for overall system reliability using standard assumptions: an intake fan that points down or up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation. I would put a reminder on my calendar to blow out the fans and internal chassis every month or two and keep it clean. Do have your car's oil changed regularly? This is no different. Especially with any PC sitting on the carpet. I could tell you horror stories about opening up tower cases that haven't been cleaned in just 1 year.

As for the PSU? If you have a front and rear fan pulling in cool air, I would set up the PSU to pull air the farthest from the carpet. If that is the video card scenario then I would go with that option.

**I don't think it is the heat you will have to worry about** as much as keeping your internal chassis clean.

Good luck and keep that bad girl clean.